# ASP MVC and Datatables: error getting data via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to load data in datatables (1.10.9) via ajax to an ASP MVC controller.

I have the following table:

```
<table id="Demo" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
         </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Demo').DataTable({
        ajax: 'GetVehicle',
        dataSrc: '',
        columns: [
            { data: 'Code' },
            { data: 'Description' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

In ASP MVC i have the following Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetVehicle()
{
   return Json(db.vehicletype.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And when this controller is called by the ajax request in the chrome inspector i see the following answer:

```
[
  {"vehicle":[],"Id":1,"Code":"Car1","Description":"Car1 Description"},
  {"vehicle":[],"Id":2,"Code":"Car2","Description":"Car2 Description"}
]
```

Why in the datatables i don't see any rows? I only see "Loading...."
In the chrome inspector, in the console, i see only this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

in the jquery.dataTables.min.js

**UPDATE**

Resolved changing the asp mvc controller into:

```
    public JsonResult GetVehicle()
    {
        return Json(new { data = db.vehicletype.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Try `ajax: { url: 'GetVehicle', dataSrc: '' }`, because `dataSrc` is a sub-option of `ajax` option.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com is right -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/661/